# Adding error message and setting parameters without changing the type double

Tags: java, types, return

I want to perform validity checks on the deposit and withdraw operations. Specifically, I don't want to allow the deposit of a negative number or a withdrawal that exceeds the current balance. I would also like to print appropriate error messages if these problems occur.
The problem that I'm having is with the "deposit" method return type. The type is set to double and I am trying to display a string if the deposit is negative. How can I do this?

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Account {

    private final double RATE = 0.035;

    private long acctNumber;
    private double balance;
    private String name;

    public Account(String owner, long account, double initial)
    {
        name = owner;
        acctNumber = account;
        balance = initial;
    }

    public double deposit(double amount)
    {
        if (amount >= 0)
        {
            balance = balance + amount;
            return balance;
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("The deposit must be greater than zero.")
        }
    }


    public double withdraw(double amount, double fee)
    {
        balance = balance - amount - fee;
        return balance;
    }

    public double addInterest()
    {
        balance += (balance * RATE);
        return balance;
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return (acctNumber + "\t" + name + "\t" + fmt.format(balance));
    }
}
```

Comment: In the normal case you are returning `balance`. Why not do that in the error case as well?

Comment: @KarlM but if I returned `balance` for the error case, how would I then display the string saying that the deposit cannot be negative?

Comment: i think in the business layer such as this you dont want to have message boxes...instead you want to throw an exception and let the GUI handle that part

Comment: `public double deposit(double amount) { if (amount >= 0) { balance += amount; } else { System.out.println("The deposit must be greater than zero."); } return balance; }`